# Laravel 5.7: QueryBuilder Get returning all records even custom query execution returning no records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

Its really strange, i am working on my real estate related website and having two tables `users` and `user_metas` where user table have all the basic details of user and user_metas having all the meta related information of user.

**user_metas** table structure

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  id   |   user_id   |   key   |   value   | created_at |  updated_at
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   |     2       |   age   |    20     | 2019-17-01 | 2019-17-01
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   2   |     3       |   age   |    40     | 2019-17-01 | 2019-17-01
```

and i just execute the query:

```
(new User)->newQuery()->where('user_type','rn')->with(['usermeta' => function($query) use ($minAge, $maxAge){
       return $query->where('key','age')->where('value','>=',$minAge);
   }])->whereHas('usermeta', function($query) use ($minAge, $maxAge){
       return $query->where('key','age')->where('value','>=',$minAge);
 })->toSql();
```

`toSql()` returning me:

[image]

when i am executing this query in phpmyadmin its returning nothing to me, but laravel `get()` returning me all records.

can anyone please tell me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because eager loaded relations (`usermeta` in your case) are exacuted as a separate SQL query. They are then mapped to the `User` model with PHP, not at your database level.

Comment: so is there any solution?

Comment: i think that should not happen, its confusing, laravel community should aware about this..

Comment: If you want a single query, you should use regular joins instead of Laravel's eager loading.

Comment: It only realized that a few months ago - was confusing to me too. What helped me a lot in understanding how eager loads work was "Laravel Debug Bar": https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar